# Issue with href xpath expression

Tags: python, xpath

I want to parse some data from site. So, what I need is to capture some values with xpath.
I have this HTML code to parse from.

```
<fieldset class="fieldgroup group-ingred">
<legend>Основные ингредиенты:</legend>
<strong><a href="/glossary/vodka"><span class="ingredient">Водка</span></a>- </strong>30 мл,<br />
<strong><span class="ingredient">Сок лимона</span> - </strong>30 мл,<br />
<strong>А также: </strong><span class="ingredient">Лёд</span>.<br />
<strong>При приготовлении понадобятся: </strong>Соломинка.</fieldset>
```

I have this for Соломинка:

```
//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']/child::text()[last()]
```

But what I also need is to parse

```
Водка 30 мл
Сок лимона 30 мл
Лед
```

as a unique values and, so xpath exparession should be different for all this three values. Is that possible? 
So for example for Водка we should include **href + span class + value between strong and br** to determinate it.
For сок лимона **span class + value between strong and br** and so on

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to to get all values as unique values, e.g. **Водка** as one value and  **30 мл** as a second value, or **Водка 30 мл** as one complete xpath result, so I'll provide both:

```
(//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//span[@class='ingredient'])
 [1]/text()   // Result: Водка
(//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//span[@class='ingredient'])
 [2]/text()   // Result: Сок лимона
(//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//span[@class='ingredient'])
 [3]/text()   // Result: Лёд

(//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//span[@class='ingredient']/
 parent::a/parent::strong/following-sibling::text())[1]
// Result: 30 мл, - to get 30 мл without the ",", use substring-before:
substring-before((//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//
span[@class='ingredient']/parent::a/parent::strong/following-sibling::text())[1],',')


(//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//span[@class='ingredient']/
 parent::strong/following-sibling::text())[1]  // Result: the 30 мл, for Сок лимона
```

To get the combined result - e.g. `Водка 30 мл` - you can use `concat()`:

```
concat(
 (//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//
    span[@class='ingredient'])[1]/text(),
    ' ',
    substring-before(
      (//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//
       span[@class='ingredient']/parent::a/parent::strong/
       following-sibling::text())[1],',')
)    // Result: Водка 30 мл

concat(
 (//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//
    span[@class='ingredient'])[2]/text(),
    ' ',
    substring-before(
      (//fieldset[@class='fieldgroup group-ingred']//
         span[@class='ingredient']/parent::strong/
         following-sibling::text())[1],',')
)   // Result: Сок лимона 30 мл
```